# How to classify archimedean solid quasicrystal made by stacking spheres

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, material-science, molecular-dynamics, granulated-materials

I have two sphere packing structures (i.e. 3N-coordinates of each structure).

One is rhombicosidodecahedron and the other one is truncated icosahedron.
They are clearly distinguished when they are polyhedra (not a packing of spheres).

However, when the structure consists of spheres. Without picking up magic number with which perfect packing is possible, It is hard to determine.

Is there any well-defined method to classify packings of structure with some defects?

If that's not possible, Is there any quantitative method to determine (truncated icosahedron)-likeness or rhombicosidodecahedron-likeness?